# Can someone find the syntax error in this simple query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions, string-function

Please help me with this error.

```
SELECT StateProvince,STRING_AGG(AddressID, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY AddressID)
FROM [SalesLT].[Address] GROUP BY StateProvince;
```

I can't find the error in this but it says

> Incorrect syntax near '('.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server 2017?

Comment: what are you exactly trying to achieve?

Comment: check which version of sql you are using `select @@version`

Comment: @GordonLinoff, if he is not using MS SQL 2017, then wouldn't the error message be different?

Comment: I don't understand why the downvote for this question, as I'm seeing the exact same thing on my **SQL2017** server. 

This will work fine...
SELECT StateProvince,STRING_AGG(AddressID, ',') 
FROM [SalesLT].[Address] GROUP BY StateProvince

   ...but as soon as you add the WITHIN GROUP () option it fails with that message.

Comment: Abhijeet, it's an old question, and you by now have solved it. Please, share with us what worked for you :-)

Answer (score 6):

Had the same issue after upgrading a database from SQL 2008R2 to 2017.  Fixed by setting the Compatability Level to 110 (or higher?)

Answer (score 2):

**FOR SQL SERVER 2017**

```
SELECT StateProvince,
       STRING_AGG(AddressID, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY AddressID) AS AddressID
FROM [SalesLT].[Address] GROUP BY StateProvince;
```

**DEMO**

> http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=69e5f9e9c5f3cab62e4b2eb9fb678299

**FOR SQL SERVER Below 2017**

```
SELECT
      StateProvince, 
      AddressID = STUFF((
          SELECT ',' + CAST(md.AddressID AS NVARCHAR)
          FROM [SalesLT].[Address] md
          WHERE m.StateProvince = md.StateProvince
          ORDER BY AddressID
          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM [SalesLT].[Address] m
Group by StateProvince
```

DEMO

> http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=a1722450c70c946e9b53ae23785f4919

Answer (score 0):

I can't see an error correlated to the message you are getting. With large data it would complain about 8000 bytes limit. This works fine under MS SQL 2017, AdventureWorks sample database (not the lite one with fewer data):

```
SELECT StateProvinceID,
       STRING_AGG(cast(AddressID as varchar(MAX)), ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY AddressID) as AdressIDS
FROM [Person].[Address] 
GROUP BY StateProvinceID;
```